# Prevent sound coming from the speakers and headset simultanously

Tags: debian, audio

On Debian 11, I always have my speakers and heaphones plugged in. When selecting sound devices, for the Line Out Built-in Audio, I get the sound in the speakers as expected. For the Heaphones Built-in Audio option, I get the sound **on both, the speakers and the heaphones!** In `alsamixer`,  Auto-Mute is disabled, since otherwise I was not getting any sound from the speakers when the headphones were plugged in.

How can I get the system to only play the audio from the headphones when both, the speakers are plugged into the rear panel of my computer, and the headphones are plugged to the front panel?

Comment: Are you using `pulseaudio`? Try swapping it for `pipewire` and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will try it soon